# Three Radar Probability

Tags: probability

Three radar sets, operating independently, are set to detect any aircraft flying through a certain area. Each set has a probability of 0.02 of ailing to detect a plane in its area. If an aircraft enters the area, what is the probability that it:

a.) goes undetected?

P(undetected | Area) = (0.02)^3

b.) is detected by all three radars?

P(Detected | Area) = 1- (0.02)^3

Is this correct? I am unsure about this.

Comment: The answer to a) is right, the answer to b) is not.

Comment: @AndréNicolas would it be (0.98)^3

Comment: Yes, that is correct. We want the probability of DDD (detect, detect, detect). Of course we are assuming independence, which is not reasonable (all three systems might have trouble in an electrical storm).

Comment: @AndréNicolas Awesome thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. You did the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As André pointed out B is incorrect.

You already said that the probability none of them works is $0.02^3$ so if the probability all three works is $1-0.002^3$ then the probability anything else happens is 0. So either all work or none works (this already feels wrong).

To see the probability none work you need to take $(1-0.002)^3=0.98^3$ since it is the probability each one doesn't work.